# Output in HTML table format

Tags: sql-server

I've a below script running and i need to get the output in a table format. Can someone assist on the below.

```
declare @xml nvarchar(max)
declare @returnvalue  nvarchar(max)
declare @body nvarchar(max)

 if exists (select 'x' from sysobjects where name ='temp_tbl')
begin
       drop table temp_tbl
end

select database_name,type,max(backup_start_date) backupdate
into temp_tbl from msdb.dbo.backupset
where database_name in 
(select name from sys.databases where recovery_model_desc='FULL')
group by  database_name,type
order by  database_name,type

if exists (select 'x' from sysobjects where name ='final_table')
begin
       drop table final_table
end

create table final_table(DBName nvarchar(500),FullBackup_date datetime,LogBackupDate datetime)
insert into final_table(DBName) 
selecT distinct Database_name From temp_tbl

update x
set x.FullBackup_date=y.backupdate
from final_table x,temp_tbl y
where x.DBname=y.database_name 
and y.type='D'

update x
set x.LogBackupDate=y.backupdate
from final_table x,temp_tbl y
where x.DBname=y.database_name 
and y.type='L'


IF (select count(*)  FROM final_table) >0 
begin
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name = 'XXX',
    @recipients = 'SSSS@at.com',
    @subject = N'Databases not backed for last 2 hrs',
    @query='select * FROM final_table where LogBackupDate < DATEADD(Hour,-2,getdate()) '
   END
```

Comment: Have a look at [Create HTML Table with SQL FOR XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086393/create-html-table-with-sql-for-xml/39487565)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
declare @result NVARCHAR(max)
create table #final_table(DBName nvarchar(500),FullBackup_date datetime,LogBackupDate datetime)
insert into #final_table(DBName,FullBackup_date,LogBackupDate) 
select 'aaa',getdate(),getdate()
union
select 'bbb',getdate(),getdate()

set @result='<html><body>'+(select 
1 TAG,
NULL PARENT,
DBName [tr!1!td!ELEMENT],
FullBackup_date [tr!1!td!ELEMENT],
LogBackupDate [tr!1!td!ELEMENT]
from #final_table for xml EXPLICIT, root('table'))+'</body></html>'

select @result
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use xml to build table body:

```
Declare @xml xml = (
Select
 Column1 as 'td', '',
 Column2 as 'td', '',
 ...
 ColumnN as 'td', ''
From table
For xml path('tr'), elements
)
```

Then convert it to nvarchar(max) => @var2

```
Declare @var2 nvarchar(max) = cast(@xml as nvarchar (max))
```

After that concatenate:

```
Declare @html_tbl nvarchar(max) =N'
    <html><body><h3>Some title</h3>
    <table border =1>
    <tr>
    <th>Col1_Name</th>
...
    <th>ColN_Name</th>
    </tr>'
+ @var2
+ N'</table></body></html>'
```